# Is it possible to read php code from other sites?

Tags: php, backend

Just a curious question. I was wondering is it possible to read a sites php/server side codes? Is there any software/method that can be used to do so? Sometimes for educational purposes, i really want to see how people form the backend infrastructure of their sites.

Comment: Provide API to read code and you will get what you want. It is also possible to include file remotely, which is not safe though. But I suppose that you really interested if you can get code from another website you don't have access to and they don't have API.... In this case, - NO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only possible if the site's owner intentionally makes the code publicly available, or if the site has a very critical security hole. Usually, no, you cannot read other people's server-side code.

After all, we'd have huge problems if you could just read any server-side code you wanted. If, say, a bank's website were built in PHP, it would be important that raw PHP files could not be read by the public: they might contain private data like database passwords, or simply make it much, much easier to find other key security issues, since, after all, which is easier—finding problems with code you can see, or code you can't see? As much as I am a fan of open-source coding, I would not put my money in any bank that makes its source code available. It's just too risky.

However, if you're interested in learning, there are plenty of open-source web applications out there. Try searching [Github](http://github.com/) for, say, projects written in PHP. It's definitely a good idea to read other people's code, and I'm sure you could find some stellar examples of real-world code if you know where to look. Additionally, if you ask nicely, a website owner may be willing to share parts of the source code with you, though probably not all of it, for security reasons. Couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Thanks man, makes a lot of sense, was curious as all :)

Comment: @Matchu Could you outline what a critical security hole could be?

Comment: @Torcellite One case would be when a website wants to expose certain files after processing them in a certain way, e.g., removewhitespace.php?file=index.js, but doesn't check that the file parameter is actually a file they want to expose, e.g., removewhitespace.php?file=removewhitespace.php.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible, except if you have the right access [permission] on their sites to do so, or you can hack the server :)

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP is only server-side, and the source is not passed to client.

Answer (score 1):

There is no software that will get the code for you. Asking the website owner to see it for educational purposes is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tell that people are even using php at all in their back end unless the site provider allows you to know that.

Answer (score 0):

As long a website is not open source (which is not going to happen), NO, you cannot see the PHP code of any page. Except, as noted, the site is badly coded or ...

Answer (score 0):

If the other site does make their code downloadable you can:

```
include_once 'http://www.theirsite.com/run_dangerous_code.php
```

But like every one else said, it is highly unlikely that this will happen.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that but it is not recommended see http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php